# Suitable technologies for a Windows video tool

Tags: windows, video-editing

A few years ago, DirectShow was around and let you manage video on DirectDraw surfaces. But since then I think both technologies have been replaced. What's currently the best solution to let you make a Windows app which can let you composite/blend/mix videos/music together? Does one still need to go the DirectX route with surfaces/textures, or is functionality found in the core Windows APIs?

Examples might be to overlay an image on a playing video, overlay two videos on top of each other with a transition effect, etc.

Apart from core technologies to handle video/audio, are their good 3rd-party libraries? Or maybe the core APIs have enough functionality on their own?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking managed code?

Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback

Short tutorial here:
http://forum.codecall.net/csharp-tutorials/20436-tutorial-playing-video-files-managed-directx.html

Comment: Cool, but is DX required these days? I kind of assumed WPF should have such features, but only from common-sense not any actual knowledge. And yes, managed is fine... no reason to use C++ for this so C# is an obvious option.

Comment: WPF, and Windows itself, are completely married to DirectX, but with more abstraction.  Even if there's another way to do it, going through DirectX is probably the best way.